Understanding [number]+つ手前
I am bit confused with the construction [number]+つ手前. Here are some examples of its usage:

終点の二つ手前で降りる

名古屋の一つ手前の駅

橋の一つ手前の角を右に曲がる

信号の 1 つ手前の角を右に曲がる


I kind of understand how it works in the first two examples. 1 means "to get off at two stations before the last station." 2 means "a station that is one station before Nagoya station" (2 does not say anything about Nagoya station, so maybe I should end with just Nagoya?). In 3 and 4, there are no train stations, so I am not sure how to interpret 一つ手前.
Also, I wonder if 前 can be used instead of 手前 in this context. For example, does 名古屋の一つ手前の駅 and 名古屋の一つ前の駅 mean the same thing?

ひとつ手前 is not specifically for train stations. Just as ひとつ手前の駅 refers to a station, ひとつ手前のバス停 refers to a bus stop, ひとつ手前の角 refers to a corner/intersection (see 角), ひとつ手前の扉 refers to a door, and so on. In Sentence 1, the "のX" part has been omitted, so you cannot tell if the sentence is about train stations or bus stops by looking at this sentence alone (終点 can be used for both).
前 and 手前 are interchangeable in all of your examples. Strictly speaking, ひとつ手前 refers to one step back in space and ひとつ前 refers to one step back in time, but both are perfectly fine in your examples because the context is about moving forward to somewhere. However, they can mean different things in other contexts. See: What is the difference between 前にある vs 手前にある?

Thank you. It is still not clear to me what 橋の一つ手前の角 and 信号の 1 つ手前の角 means. I am not sure where are "corners" of a bridge and traffic lights.

@weeab00 There's really no difference between 名古屋の一つ手前の駅 and 橋の一つ手前の角. The former means the station just before Nagoya Station, the latter means the corner/crossing just before the bridge.

Here "corner" is slightly-metaphorically a crossing or intersection. It's the same as how in English we might say something like "keep going on Main Street for three more lights" - meaning, until one has reached the third intersection with a traffic light, beyond the current position. 信号の 1 つ手前の角 doesn't imply that the 角 is part of a 信号, but rather that it is reached before arriving at the 信号. の is broad and doesn't just describe possession. So it's the 角 which is 1 つ手前 "of" the 信号.

Ah I see, so 角 in this context refers to street intersection? So 橋の一つ手前の角 means a street intersection that is one intersection away from the street intersection that has bridge?

@weeab00 The bridge itself doesn't have to have an intersection next to it. 橋の一つ手前の角 refers to, among the intersections that lies between the speaker and the bridge,  the one closest to the bridge. The intersection itself may be several hundred meters away from the bridge.

Following this logic, 橋の二つ手前の角 refers to the intersection that is second closest to the bridge, right?

@weeab00 Yes. If it's like "‍♂️➡️➡️➡️", the intersection on the left is 橋の2つ手前の角.

@weeab00 Strictly speaking, the basic meaning of 角(かど) is "turning" or "corner", but practically, we often say this including intersections. A single zigzag road has many 角.
